# Active Directory & firewall-cmd

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine, firewall, firewalld, active-directory

I'm using a RHEL based VM as a router and I'm trying to get AD running on the network but I'm not being successful at it.

When I set up the interfaces on the LAN side to the trusted zone everything works flawlessly, but when I set them in the internal zone (after adding the ports I'll list below) nothing works as it should be; can't even discover the AD Controller.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-port={135,137,139,445,389,636,3268,3269,88,53,1512,42,9389,1024-5000,49152-6535}/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-port={135,137,138,445,389,500,88,53,1512,42,4500}/udp
```

Comment: Correct this 49152-6535[5].

Answer (score 1):

The `--permanent` flag doesn't apply the changes immediately. Here's the relevant section from `man firewall-cmd`, with my emphasis:

> The permanent option `--permanent` can be used to set options permanently. **These changes are not effective immediately**, only after service restart/reload or system reboot

I would recommend you test without the `--permanent` so that you can see changes effective immediately. When you have a working solution, reapply the instruction but with `--permanent`.

You should also fix the typo `6535` which should be `65535`. I can't tell if that's a typo copying into this question or a typo in your original command, but either way it should be addressed.

Comment: Indeed it’s a nice practice so I don’t  have to be restarting. But even then it doesn’t work.

Comment: @DefaultVLAN answer amended